# Not able to import RX in anglar4

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, reactive-programming, rxjs5

i am just started to learn the rxjs programming and want to implement it in my angular 4 application.

i followed this [blog](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/installation.html) and installed rxjs using the command

> npm install rxjs-es

but when i try to import it and use i am getting an error import Rx

> from 'rxjs/Rx';

i followed some blog where it has adviced me to make some changes in the systemjs.config file, but i dont have a systemjs.config file in my application. i created my application using the angular cli command

Comment: You are using Typescript, correct? in that case try `npm install rxjs` instead of `rxjs-es` - the ES-Version is just if you are using ES6

Comment: after doing this command "npm install rxjs", how should i import it?

Comment: ok, so in typescript i have to use import { Observable} from "rxjs/Rx"; to import the observables directly unlike in es6 where they have to import the RX and then use observables like this RX.Observables, am i right?

Comment: yes, you reference directly just stuff you want to actually use. Looks cleaner imho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rxjs is already part of angular so there is no need to install it manually via npm.

Just import components you want to use like e.g.

```
import { Subject, Subscription } from "rxjs/Rx";
```